# How to Format The WordPress Accordion Title into 2 sections

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the Divi Builder in WordPress to make a list of patents in the accordion format. However, I would like to format the accordion title (of each accordion element) so that on the left is the patent#, and on the right is the title of the patent.

To do this, I would like to know how I can split the title into 2 separate sections; 1 where I can put the title number, and the other where I can type the name of the patent. Sort of like this:

[image: sketch of accordion title format goal]
Another sketch to show what I want it to look like: [sketch of the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfcDs.png)

Again I am using Divi Builder to do this as I am a novice using WordPress. But I am assuming I would have to write some custom CSS to format the title in this way in the Divi Builder.

1. First is it possible to do what I am trying to do?
2. If so how can I do this (in the Divi Builder environment)?

Comment: Your "sketch" is incomprehensible, what does it mean to split into two headings? Can I get more details? Why should we break our brains, because you are too lazy to portray what you want normally, make us an understandable design

Comment: If we are talking not only about style, but also about heading tags, I think you cannot do without a tambourine, it is impossible to do this using the admin panel, you will need to change the html on the output (filter the_content) in php or with js after loading the page

Comment: Good point. Added another sketch of what the goal for the accordion title is. You see in the first image is the accordion title as it is now (if you ignore the red markings). The goal is to have the patent title text tabulated and to the right, while the patent number is to the left of the title. Please let me know if this isn't clear. 

I'll have to look into this some more, but I don't think heading tags is the issue. I want to break the title element of the accordion into two sections as seen in my pic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all of our requirements can be met by means of ready-made tools for building a website.

In such cases, we are forced to write "fixes" in such individual cases.

I offer you a js script that does the following:

Searches for titles with text that meets the following requirements:

1. Starts with #
2. After a hash without spaces, numbers
   Example: #111
   Wraps the found in the span with the class specified in the configuration (at the very top of the file)

I tested [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Divi/accordion/)

```js
(function() {
    // Config
  let classFirstHeading = 'my-heading';
  let headerSelector = '.et_pb_toggle_title';  // You can replace to your selector of heading
  // end config;
  
  var DOMReady = function(callback) {
    if (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") {
      callback();
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    } else if (document.attachEvent) {
      document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function() {
        if (document.readyState != "loading") {
          callback();
        }
      });
    }
  }
    function updateHeading() {
    let headings = document.querySelectorAll(headerSelector);
    headings.forEach(el => {
        let textHeading = el.innerText;
      let regexp = /^\#\d+/;  
      if(textHeading && regexp.test(textHeading.trim())) {
        el.innerHTML = textHeading.replace(regexp, (match) => {
            return '<span class="'+classFirstHeading+'">'+match+'</span> ';
        });
      }
    });
  }
  window.updateHeading = updateHeading; // Give access from outside
    DOMReady(() => {
    updateHeading();
    
    
    /* Test, you can remove this section */
    let styleEl = document.createElement('style'); styleEl.type = 'text/css';
    let css = `
        .${classFirstHeading} {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 23px;
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-right: 15px;   
        padding: 10px 15px 10px 0;
        border-right: 2px solid #000;
      }    
    `;
    styleEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(styleEl);
    
    /*************************************/
  });   
  
})();
```

```html
<h5 class="et_pb_toggle_title">#111 What is your refund policy?</h5>
```

If you don't know where to insert such code, install the **Custom CSS and JS in Header & Footer** plugin and just copy my js code to your page where you use the accordion

Comment: Thanks for this information. I have yet to try it. But I certainly will. Also gave me some ideas. I am also wondering if there is something as simple as doing a newline in the accordion title? So Instead of sections side-by-side, at least the patent # can be below the title in a new line. THanks again!